# React Link onClick setState returns undefined

Tags: reactjs

I have a component with a button which I've changed to `Link` component, since I need to scroll to a specific location on the webpage and set a component state.

The function works when there's a `button` component used, and console.logs the needed value. However, when changing the `button` to `Link`, the value returned is `undefined`.

The component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-scroll";

class Scroll extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: ""
    };

    this.setValue = this.setValue.bind(this);
  }

  setValue = e => {
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
    console.log(this.state.value);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Link
          value="feature"
          onClick={this.setValue}
          className="action-button"
          to="signup-wrapper"
          activeClass="active"
          spy={true}
          smooth={true}
          offset={-100}
          duration={200}
        >
          See Feature
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Scroll;
```

How to make it work so that the Link component both scrolls down to a specific element and successfully changes the state?

Comment: You should know that `setState` is async so your console log will not show the updated value of the state.

Comment: yes, I'm doing several clicks on the component. But whenever I'm changing Link to button, console.log gives me the string "feature", whereas with Link it's undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<Link>` component **does not have a value** like a button or an input. I guess you need to access the `value` attribute using [element.getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) :

```
  setValue = e => {
    this.setState({ value: e.target.getAttribute('value') });
  };
```

Also, keep in mind `setState` is async so using `console.log()` just after will display the previous value, not the new one.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I need to access the string in the "value" attribute. Will this work if I specify "value" instead of "to"?

Comment: Awesome. I updated my answer with `value` instead of `to` but using such a name might be confusing.

Comment: I did, the reason I didn't do that earlier is stackoverflow blocking me from accepting an answer for some 10 minutes :)

Answer (score 1):

This answer requires your code to be refactored as I am using props instead of a value on the Link component, but I've created some boilerplate code with some comments so you know whats going on.

When I found out about hooks, my life was changed forever. I would strongly suggest watching the videos on youtube ([90% Cleaner React With Hooks](https://youtu.be/dpw9EHDh2bM)) from the guys at Facebook.

If you copy the code and remove the comments you will see how much cleaner pure components are instead of classes and standard components (although there are some exceptions to the rule).

Hope this helps, and happy to answer any questions

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-scroll";

export default function Scroll(props) {
    // No contructor!

    // This is a two pronged attack:
    //  - foo: This is the variable you want to declare
    //  - setFoo: This is the function that will update it.
    //            this saves a lot of time writing out this.setState({...})
    const [foo, setFoo] = useState("");

    // This is like an event listener, the code inside the function will be 
    // exectuted whenever the specified variables stored in [] changes -                 
    // like ComponentDidUpdate with a filter.
    useEffect(() => console.log(foo), [foo]);

    // You can leave this array empty, and it will run the code inside on mount. Useful for fetching data from an API asyncrounously.

    // Render function is not required, just return a jsx object
    return (
        <div>
            <ScrollButton value="feature" text="See Feature" setFoo={setFoo} />
            <div style={{ height: 5000 }} />
            <div className="signup-wrapper">Content to scroll to</div>
        </div>
    );
}

function ScrollButton(props) {
    return (
        <Link
            onClick={() => props.setFoo(props.value)}
            className="action-button"
            to="signup-wrapper"
            activeClass="active"
            spy={true}
            smooth={true}
            offset={-100}
            duration={200}
        >
            {props.text}
        </Link>
    );
}
```